# Check if next element of list is the same as previous one

Tags: python, list, loops

```
l=['1', '1', '3289', '3289', '3290', '3290', '3291', '3291', '3292', '3292', '3293', '3293', '3294', '3294']
```

I want to do a some kind of loop that checks if the number is the same as next one. If not then do something.

I came up with this:

```
for idx, x in enumerate(l):
  if idx+1 <= len(l)-1:
    print(idx)
    if x[idx] == x[idx+1]:
      pass
    else:
      print('cat')  # do something
  else:
    pass
```

but i keep passing the list index. I have no idea how to make this if statement.

For example i would like to insert missing numbers into the list like so:

```
['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3',....,'3288', '3288', '3289', '3289', '3290', '3290', '3291', '3291', '3292', '3292', '3293', '3293', '3294', '3294']
```

Comment: So you want to have all the numbers in a range but every number should be twice. Am i right?

Comment: I would like to add all missing numbers in the list twice.

Comment: Determine min, max of the list and generate new list with every number repeated.

Comment: the original "next index" will change as you keep adding and moving forward, so instead you can loop backwards through the indexes, eg: len=10, so go 10,9,8,..0. That way when you add elements it wont affect your loop's index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want;

```
l = [1, 2, 34, 55, 66]

res = []

for i in range(1, l[-1] + 1):
    res.append(i)
    res.append(i)

print(res)
```

if you want the `res` list to start from the same element as the starting element of the given list, then change the `range` of for-loop as;

```
for i in range(l[0], l[-1] + 1):
```

Rest is same.

Also if the input list is not sorted;

```
inputList = [2, 1, 45, 23, 54, 54, 54, 5, 4, 67, 22 ]

sortedList = sorted(inputList)
```

After this the rest is same i.e, apply the above code on `sortedList` now.

Comment: It works but only when my starting number is 1. And if it was 5 it would append numbers before 5 and I don't want that.

Comment: i already edited the answer for every condition. Also i am assuming that your input list is sorted. If not please sort that first by using the in-built `sorted` function

Comment: I had to change this bit `for i in range(l[0], l[-1] + 1):` Now it takes first value of my list and adds between this value and the last. 
Thank you for help i will mark it

Comment: I will edit my answer in case the input list is not sorted. Please check that.

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
l = ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3',....,'3288', '3288', '3289', '3289', '3290', '3290', '3291', '3291', '3292', '3292', '3293', '3293', '3294', '3294']
res = [i for i in range(l[0], l[-1] + 1) for _ in range(2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a while loop like this.

```py
l=['1', '1', '3289', '3289', '3290', '3290', '3291', '3291', '3292', '3292', '3293', '3293', '3294', '3294']

idx = 0

while idx < len(l)-1:
    if l[idx] == l[idx+1]: # to check if they are same
        print(l[idx], l[idx+1], 'are same') # do something
    else:
        print(l[idx], l[idx+1], 'are not same') # do something else

    idx+=2
```

You need to do idx+=2 because idx+=1 will go to each and every element, but I think you want to check if `l[0]==l[1], l[2]==l[3]....`.